# How to upload files to Soundcloud using Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, audio, soundcloud

I am building an application that would upload audio on SoundCloud and get the URL of the uploaded track using Codeigniter.

I need to know how to upload the file to SoundCloud.

How do I do it? I have not used API thing before and I don't find a proper tutorial or a guide to how to upload it. So if anybody can help me with this, please answer my question here.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the SoundCloud CodeIgniter Library, from GitHub. I have never used it, but I do have an upcoming project that will use SoundCloud, so for now this is all I can do;

https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Soundcloud-Library

Comment: I tried same library, but was not able to solve problem.